# Selecting classic mode on login still shows Launcher

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher, gnome, gsettings

I was running Unity in Natty when I tried to activate the Rotate and Cube effects. That broke Unity and I had to restore the Unity original configuration by invoking

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

and

```
unity --reset
```

I have now got back Unity and re-tweaked it, but *something* I did in between now gives me the Launcher on the left side when I choose Ubuntu Classic instead of Ubuntu when I log in. I seem to be in a hybrid state where I can get use of both the traditional (gnome 2?) functionality and also Unity.

How can I restore the Ubuntu Classic interface to its original non-hybrid state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Log into Ubuntu Classic,
- Open the *CompizConfig Settings Manager* (`ccsm`), and
- untick the *Ubuntu Unity Plugin* in the *Desktop* section.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Classic then comes out as original but Unity loses Launcher and becomes unusable. Does it have to do with CSSM profiles? I have `Default` and `unity` and use unity.